# zf2 doctrine editaction with jquery datepicker - do not allow recursion

Tags: php, jquery, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

this is the error i get :

Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#datadocarro").datepicker({
          changeMonth:true,
          changeYear:true,
          yearRange:"-100:+100",
          dateFormat:"dd MM yy"
          });



        $("#inspecao").datepicker({                
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true,
            yearRange:"-100:+100",
            dateFormat:"dd MM yy"
            });       
 });
</script>

<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('datadocarro')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php
  //  the error is hapening here
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('datadocarro'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('datadocarro'));
?></dd>
```

in the add action i have the same code on the view and is working

on the edit action view i get the error

it works now no error 
but jquery datepicker is not working

```
<dt><?php
$ytestevq=$form->get('datadocarro');
$datecarroElement = new Zend\Form\Element\Date('datadocarro');
$datadocarrov=$form->get('datadocarro')->getValue()->format('Y-m-d');

    echo $this->formLabel($form->get('datadocarro')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php 
    echo $this->formElement($datecarroElement->setValue($form->get('datadocarro')->getValue()->format('Y-m-d')));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($datecarroElement);
?></dd>
```

form code

```
        $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'datadocarro',

        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'Date',

            'required' => 'required',
            'class' => 'demoHeaders',
            'id' => 'datadocarro',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => _('Car Date'),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us the configuration of the 'datadocarro' element, and also whether you are hydrating the date as string into that element or as a Date object.

If you are storing a Date object into a text element, the form will throw this error when rendering.
You can either format the Date to a string or if you wanna use a HTML5 element then you use Zf2's Date element.